# Getting a json attribute from URL

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

So here's my script:

```
import requests
import urllib
import json

url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560'
response = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
print(response["offers"])
```

and after grabbing the page source of https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560

I want to grab this data

```
"offers":{"@type":"Offer","url":"https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560","priceCurrency":"USD","price":1449.95,"priceValidUntil":"4/7/2021","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock"}
```

More specifically, `price` and `priceValidUntil`

from some googling I think this would be the way to do it but since there's so much data within the webpage I think it is taking my script a ton of time to run.

Is there a more efficient way of getting this json data and am I grabbing this data correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to load the json data from HTML page:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
}
url = "https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZLINE-Kitchen-and-Bath-36-DuraSnow-Stainless-Steel-Range-Hood-with-Hand-Hammered-Copper-Shell-8654HH-36-8654HH-36/311287560"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(
    soup.select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]').contents[0]
)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print("Price:", data["offers"]["price"])
print("Price valid until:", data["offers"]["priceValidUntil"])
```

Prints:

```
Price: 1449.95
Price valid until: 4/8/2021
```

Comment: thanks a ton!!! I'll try this out. This example was also great since I'll have a couple more projects and I know this is going to help out!